# When to use EPS instead of XPS (aka Styrodur [TM] and Styropor [TM]) for insulation?

Tags: insulation

What are the pros and cons of expanded polystyrene foam (EPS) (known as BASF Trademark Styropor) and extruded polystyrene foam (XPS) (known as BASF Trademark Styrodur) cards for thermal insulation between an cellar wall and the soil?

All I could find out yet was that EPS has larger pores and is softer and lighter than XPS. I could not find good sources for all other statements like "EPS can absorb more water".

Please add sources to your answer as there seem to be some legends around these materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPS is not suitable for soil contact. XPS is.
[see (dow.com)](http://msdssearch.dow.com/PublishedLiteratureDOWCOM/dh_0568/0901b803805681b5.pdf?filepath=styrofoam/pdfs/noreg/178-00414.pdf&fromPage=GetDoc)